# Proof of a property of the fundamental solution of laplace equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Fundamental solution of Laplace equation for d>3 is $\phi(x)=\frac{|x|^{2-d}}{d(d-2)\alpha_d},x\neq0.$

1. Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^d$ be an open, bounded set with $C^1$ boundary, $u\in C^2(\overline{\Omega})$ and for $x\in\mathbb{R}^d$ we define $\phi_x(y)=\phi(y-x),y\neq x.$
   Prove that $$u(x)=\int_\Omega -\phi_x\Delta ud\lambda+\int_{\delta\Omega}\phi_x\frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu}dS-\int_{\delta \Omega}u\frac{\partial\phi_x}{\partial\nu}dS$$
2. Prove that for $\varphi\in D(\mathbb{R}^d)$ (set of bump/test functions) the following applies (using the property from 1.)
   $$\varphi(0)=\int_{R^d}-\phi_x\Delta\varphi d\lambda$$

I have already managed to prove 1., but I don't see how to get the 2. property from it. Any help is welcome.

Comment: Is there a typo in 2.? Clearly there are tests functions for which $\varphi(0) \neq 0$.

Comment: You are right, fixed the typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to show the first equality in 2., i.e. $$\varphi(0) = \int_{\mathbb R^d} - \phi_x \Delta\varphi \mathrm d \lambda,$$

it might be helpful to consider a ball $\Omega = B(0,2r)$ of radius $2r$, such that $\operatorname{supp}(\varphi) \subseteq B(0,r)$ and set $u = \varphi$. Now $u$ vanishes on a neighborhood of the boundary $\partial \Omega = S_{2r}$ of $\Omega$, how does that help in eliminating terms in the formula in 1.?